# How do I edit an interface builder object programmatically?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, attributes, interface-builder, colors

I created a label using Interface Builder, and now I want to set the background color of the label using code instead of IB's color picker.  (I want to do this so that I can define the color using RGB and eventually change the colorspace for the label.)

I'm in cocoa.  How do I edit the attributes of an IB object using code?

My code looks like this:

```
//.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IBAppDelegate : NSObject {

    UILabel  *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end



//.m file


#import "IBAppDelegate.h"

@implementation IBAppDelegate

@synthesize label;

(memory stuff...)

@end
```

Comment: Less significant: The IBOutlet macro should go on the instance variable, not the property.

Comment: It's actually recommended that the IBOutlet macro be on the property, not the instance variable; this lets the instance variable have a different name and emphasizes the use of KVC to set the outlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application
{
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1f
                                                 green:0.2f
                                                  blue:0.3f
                                                 alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  I knew it had to be something simple.  I looked everywhere and couldn't find a straight answer.

Answer (score 2):

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]

There's nothing special about the objects in your XIB file. They're just normal objects.